# float right is not working in my case , what should i do?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi all , As show in the picture , if i use float right , the phone image will be after the hamburger icon.

what should i do to position the phone icon before the hamburger icon except using margin it all the way ?

```
    <div class="top_nav" style="position:fixed; width=100%;">
    <div class="top_nav_menu top_nav_left_log_part">
        <a href="index.html" style="padding:auto;">
            <img id="img_nav_left_png" src="img/fujitsu.svg" alt="" style="height:80px; width=83px;padding-top:17px;padding-bottom:23px;">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="top_nav_menu_middle_id" class="top_nav_menu top_nav_menu_middle">
        <ul class="top_nav_ul">
            <li class="top_nav_li nav_menu"><a href="services.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Database migration and consulting services">Services</a></li>
            <li class="top_nav_li nav_menu"><a href="support.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="24/7 and business hours support options for PostgreSQL users">Support</a></li>
            <li class="top_nav_li nav_menu"><a href="training.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Training courses for DBAs and developers">Training</a></li>
            <li class="top_nav_li nav_menu"><a href="product.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="FUJITSU Enterprise Postgres and PostgreSQL">Product</a></li>
            <li class="top_nav_li nav_menu"><a href="solutions.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="End-to-end PostgreSQL solutions">Solutions</a></li>
            <li class="top_nav_li nav_menu"><a href="contact.html" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top_nav_menu top_nav_contact_part">
        <ul class="top_nav_ul">
            <li id = "top_nav_phone_log_li" class="top_nav_li" >
                <a href="tel://+6194549191" style="padding-top:25px;">
                    <img id="img_nav_phone_png" src="img/phone_icon.svg" alt="" style="height:100%; margin-left:20px; width:26px;height:30px;">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id = "top_nav_phone_number_li" class="top_nav_li  "><a href="tel://+6194549191" class="number">+61 2 9454 9191</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="top_nav_menu top_nav_right_log_part">
        <ul class="top_nav_ul">
            <li class="top_nav_li top_nav_right_log">
               <img id="img_nav_right_png" src="img/PostgreSQL.svg" alt="Contact-number" style="height:40px;width:175px;">
            </li>
            <li class="hamberger_icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" id="hamberger">&#9776;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

CSS code

```
.top_nav {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-color: #F7F9F8;
}

.top_nav_menu {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    /*  border-style: solid;*/
    border-color: red;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.top_nav_left_log_part {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.top_nav_right_log_part {
    float: right;
}

ul.top_nav_ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*    background-color: #333;*/
}

li.top_nav_li {
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    /*    border-style: solid;*/
}

li.top_nav_li a {
    display: inline-block;
    /*    color: white;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    /*    padding-left: 16px;*/
    /*    padding: 10px 16px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

li.nav_menu:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

li.nav_menu_active {
    border-bottom-color: #ff0000;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
}

li.top_nav_li a:hover:active {
    /*    background-color: red;;*/
}

li.nav_menu a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #322f31;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

li#nav_menu_show {
    display: none;
}

li#nav_menu_show a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: red;
}

img#img_nav_left_png,
img#img_nav_right_png,
img#img_nav_phone_png {
    display: block;
    /*  width: 25px; */
    margin: auto;
}

li.top_nav_right_log {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}

ul.top_nav_ul li.icon {
    display: none;
}


/*hamberger size*/

#hamberger {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}

.icon {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.number {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

li.hamberger_icon {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 17px;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1170px) {
    /*  .top_nav_contact_part{
  display:none;
  }*/
    li.nav_menu a {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #322f31;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .top_nav_left_log_part {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .top_nav_right_log {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    id#img_nav_phone_png {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1160px) {
    .top_nav_menu_middle {
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
    }
    li.nav_menu {
        background-color: grey;
        float: none;
    }
    li.top_nav_right_log {
        display: none;
    }
    li.hamberger_icon {
        font-size: 30px;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1165px) {
    li.top_nav_right_log {
        display: block;
    }
    li.nav_menu {
        float: left;
    }
    /*    .top_nav_menu_middle{
      display: block;
    }*/
}

.top_nav_menu_middle_display {
    display: block;
}


/*Navi Responsive */


/* When the screen is less than 768 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */


@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .top_nav_menu_middle{
    display: none;
  }
 #top_nav_phone_number_li{
  display:none;
  }/*
  .top_nav_contact_part{

      : right;

    }
*/

  ul.top_nav_ul li.top_nav_right_log{
    display: none;
  }
  ul.top_nav_ul li.hamberger_icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the css code?

Comment: Can you please post your current css that goes along with this code?

Comment: sure i apologise that

Comment: You haven't put float right on the phone

Comment: @ Carol McKay if i put float right on the phone, it will position after the hamburger ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Flexbox for this.

Your html would look something like this:

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
   <div class="telephone"></div>
   <div class="hamburger-menu-icon"><div>
</div>
```

Your CSS would look like this:

```
.navigation-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: end;
}

.telephone {
  order: -1;
}
```

`justify-content: end;` would be kind of the same as `float: right;`
When you tell .telephone to have `order: -1;` you tell it to be in front of the other elements (hamburger-menu-icon).

Guide to flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you would like I could create a codepen. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a flex looking like this:

[phone symbol] [--------------flex-spacer--------------] [hamburger symbol]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="symbol">
        phone symbol
    </div>
    <div class="flex-spacer">
    </div>
    <div class="symbol">
        hamburger symbol
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.symbol {
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
.flex-spacer {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```